# Как отменить действие в событии?

Tags: jquery

Есть js-событие, в котором выполняется такой код `$('.element').stop().slideUp('fast');`
Можно ли как-то отменить `slideUp` не имея доступа к данному коду?
т.е. можно ли как-то отменить `slideUp` из другого скрипта?

```
LA.utils.eventManager.subscribe('LA:AjaxShopFilter:success', function(e, response, url, element){
    ...
    some code
    $('.element').stop().slideUp('fast');
}
```

т.е. нужно отменить только `.slideUp`, других действий в этом событии не нужно отменять. поэтому всё событие отменять нельзя

**P.S.**

```
LA.utils.eventManager.subscribe('LA:AjaxShopFilter:success', function(e, response, url, element){
    $('.element').clearQueue();
});
```

это не работает

Comment: или нужно переопределять всё событие?

Comment: Возможно вам поможет `clearQueue`.

Comment: @And, что-то не работает:  `$('.element').clearQueue();`

Comment: получилось с `setTimeout`